# Binding unordered lists in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm somewhat new to prolog, and I'm trying to figure out how to achieve binding the elements of a list when order does not matter. I demonstrated that in the two last lines of my code. It seemed trivial to do this, but it fails to bind.

```
fh(Hand) :-
   is_card(R, _, C1),
   is_card(R, _, C2),
   is_card(R, _, C3),
   C1 \== C2,
   C2 \== C3,
   C1 \== C3,

   is_card(RR, _, D1),
   is_card(RR, _, D2),
   R \= RR,
   D1 \== D2,
   is_set(Hand),
   list_to_set([C1,C2,C3,D1,D2], Hand).
```

I would appreciate some hints. (predicate name and functionality concealed to prevent plagiarism)

Comment: Are you using the is_set and list_to_set from library(lists)? Maybe list_to_set expects some order, it says "True when Set has the same elements as List in the same order." I don't know how to run your code so I have no idea.

Comment: That's true, so apparently it's only a set in the sense that elements are not repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct your hand with more strict conditions to establish unique elements by placing an order on them rather than just checking that they are different:

```
fh(Hand) :-
   is_card(R, _, C1),
   is_card(R, _, C2),
   is_card(R, _, C3),
   C1 @< C2,
   C2 @< C3,

   is_card(RR, _, D1),
   is_card(RR, _, D2),
   dif(R, RR),
   D1 @< D2.
```

This way, you're using ordering to construct your card hands such that you don't have any repeats. Since you don't care what the order is, having a particular order does not interfere with requirements and provides a means to establish uniqueness.

Comment: I'm not working with numbers. Is there a way to define `@<` for a compound(card)?

Comment: @lamino `@<` works with any kind of term. For example `a @< b` is true. `foo(a) @< foo(b)` is true. Etc... In your case, the actual ordering doesn't matter as long as a consistent ordering is applied. If you look it up in the Prolog documentation, it will describe the `@` relational operators in more detail.

Comment: @lamino you need to clarify your original problem. You're missing a lot of details about what your requirements are. If `is_card/3` is in your fact database, there shouldn't be any variables in the results. So an example would be extremely helpful. Show what the facts look like. Or if `is_card/3` is a predicate, show the predicate.

Comment: Sorry, you were absolutely correct. I had to add permutation for getting all the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation available in library(lists), it seems that for your use case it might be best to represent a set as a sorted list without duplicates, made with `sort/2`.

Here is what I get:

```
?- A = [2,3,1],
   B = [1,1,2,3,2,3],
   sort(A, S),
   sort(B, S).
A = [2, 3, 1],
B = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3],
S = [1, 2, 3].
```

`sort(A, S)` will make sure that S is an ordered list with the same elements as A, and `sort(B, S)` will make sure that if you make a set from B it is the same as A.

I see that the implementation of `is_set/1` is probable the same as `length(Set, Lenght), sort(Set, Sorted), length(Sorted, Len).` but I can't find the definition of `'$skip_list'`. But I see:

```
?- '$skip_list'(Len, [2,3,1], Tail).
Len = 3,
Tail = [].
```

Comment: `is_set(X) :- sort(X,X).` suffices

Comment: @CapelliC i think it suffices if X is already a sorted set and i thought that the problem is that [2,3,1] should also be "set"

Comment: is_set/1 has no error conditions, does not instantiate its arguments and indeed succeeds if the elements are not in standard order.   Fixed the `det` to `semidet`

Answer (score 0):

Like the other commenters, I'll assume you are using `is_set/1` from SWI-Prolog's library. In your code you have a call

```
is_set(Hand)
```

where `Hand` is a free variable. Your goal seems to be to use this as a sort of generator or "type declaration", but that doesn't work:

```
?- is_set(X).
false.
```

The [documentation of `is_set/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is_set/1) reads in part:

> is_set(@Set)  [det]
>
> True if Set is a proper list without duplicates.

There are a few things going on here. According to [SWI's mode documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes), `det` means "Succeeds exactly once without a choice point", and `@` means "Argument will not be further instantiated than it is at call-time.". Putting both of these together, `is_set/1` *cannot* be a generator since it doesn't enumerate solutions: It does not instantiate its argument to even a single solution (`@`), and even if it did, it would not succeed more than once (`det`). (In fact, a `det` predicate should never fail, but `is_set/1` does; this seems to be a documentation bug, the correct annotation would be `semidet`.)

So: You cannot use `is_set/1` as a generator, only as a type check. But even as a type check it doesn't help you here since a free variable is certainly *not* "a proper list". However, you don't need either a generator or a type check here. Remove the `is_set/1` call, `list_to_set/2` alone should do what you want.